# Using 1st SQL select statement results for 2nd select statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I'd like some help combining Multiple SQL queries into one...

I have a search box for orderid or sampleref. An order may have up to 99 sampleref in it so I want the customer to be able to pull up a list of all sampleref associated with their order number regardless of if they search by orderid or one of their sampleref. Essentially what I want to do is,

```
SELECT `orderid` as OrderNumber FROM `results` WHERE `sampleref` = 'TEST12345';
SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `orderid` = OrderNumber GROUP BY `sampleref`;
```

For clarity I'm putting this into a PHP script for a Maria DB mysql server

Here is a sample database

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | orderid | sampleref |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |  101388 | TEST12345 |
|  2 |  101388 | TEST54321 |
|  3 |  333444 | ABC123    |
|  4 |  333444 | ABC321    |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Thanks

Henry

Comment: For clarity, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `SET Order_Number as OrderNumber` is not a valid SQL query.  Can you explain what your second "query" is supposed to be doing?

Comment: I've updated my SQL query with my work so far as you can see I want to pass the order number returned from the first into the 2nd query, although I think perhaps this could be written as a single query also

Comment: For the second query (after update), `SELECT *` is incompatible with `GROUP BY sampleref`.  What is the reason you are doing `GROUP BY` there?

Comment: To reduce any duplicate results. The error I get from PHPmyadmin is that OrderNunber is an Unknown Column

Comment: What's the definition of a duplicate result here?  Can you add sample data?

Comment: Let's forget that for now, this comes into play for some other reasons buts it's not the stumbling block. So I'll remove it for now. The issue is still getting the OrderNumber from that first part to the second. Is the syntax wrong ?

Comment: Is your result table having one record per sampleref for every order? if so, then something like this would work => 
select r2.orderid, r2.sampleref from result r
join result r2 on r.orderid = r2.orderid 
where r.sampleref = 'TEST12345'

Comment: Sorry broken Leg so working from a phone here... Added my database to the original post.

Comment: So essentially the search query could be TEST12345, TEST54321 or 101388 and regardless the results should be rows 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

Following will give you what you are looking for.

```
select r2.orderid, r2.sampleref 
from result r 
join result r2 on r.orderid = r2.orderid 
where r.sampleref = 'TEST12345' or r.orderid = <orderid>
```

Comment: Some explanation of how this works may help OP (and others) understand the solution.

Comment: @Gro nice however this doesn't help me if the user searches using the Order Number instead...

Comment: @HenryAspden Just add an OR predicate in the where clause for orderid. Modified the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `or` with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM results r
WHERE r.orderid = $orderid OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM results r2
              WHERE r2.orderid = r.orderid AND r2.sampleref = $sampleref
             );
```

Note:  This takes two parameters -- either the order id or the sample ref.  The first condition returns everything with the same order, if that is given.  The second returns everything with the same order as the given sample ref.